# ReactiveUI - Views not rendering properly (or in full)

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui, mahapps.metro

I'm in the process of starting a new project, using `ReactiveUI` and `MahApps.Metro`. The first hurdle I've hit is a problem of views not showing in their entirety. I have a `Window`, and in that `Window` I have a `ViewModelViewHost` from the RxUI library. It is a simple container for a nested view-model. The ActiveItem binding is properly binded to the view-model of the User Control, and the `Button` from the user control is visible on screen.

What I expect to see is a `Window` with a dark gray background and a button in the middle. What I see is the `Window` with its default background and a `Button` in the middle. This is not right. If I remove the button, I see nothing on the `Window`, only the default background.

It seems the `ViewModelViewHost` is only showing the actual contents of a UserControl and is disregarding what isn't considered a real Control, such as grids etc.

Has anyone come across this behaviour before?

```
<mah:MetroWindow x:Class="...MainWindow"
                 xmlns:mah="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:rx="clr-namespace:ReactiveUI;assembly=ReactiveUI"
                 WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
                 ShowTitleBar="False"
                 ShowCloseButton="False"
                 ShowMaxRestoreButton="False"
                 ShowMinButton="False"
                 Height="768"
                 Width="1024">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <rx:ViewModelViewHost ViewModel="{Binding ActiveItem}" />
    </Grid>
</mah:MetroWindow>


<UserControl x:Class="...NestedView"
             Name="TheUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Auto"
             TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Auto"
             d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="1024">

    <Grid Background="DarkGray">
        <Button Width="200" Height="100" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This won't be a ReactiveUI problem, just a simple WPF one.

The `ViewModelViewHost` is centered in your window. While your `UserControl` has a `DesignHeight` and `DesignWidth` set, when it's rendered at runtime it will automatically size itself to the height and width of its content - the `Button`.

Add `VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` to your `ViewModelViewHost` declaration and remove the other two `Alignment` attributes (they default to Stretch) and it should stretch its contents to the size of the `Window` while centering any item that has a fixed size.

Comment: Didn't change a thing unfortunately. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @BlackBox what I wrote would apply if the only child was the ViewModelViewHost - I've just noticed there's a grid there too. Unless you're adding anything else to the window, I'd remove the Grid and do as above, else I'll update the answer when I've had chance to test it.

Comment: I just removed the grid from the Window, and the view rendered as expected. But in the user control, should I want a grid with 2 columns, 1 with a button, another with a `ViewModelViewHost`, the same problem reppears in column 1. How can this be overcome? In the past where I've used content controls with Caliburn.Micro I never had such issues.

Comment: @BlackBox I will test in an hour or so, but I'm fairly sure it's because your Grid was centred. Centring will mean he Grid sizes to the size of its contents, and ViewModelViewHost will only take as much space as its content. If you change the Grid alignments to Stretch, ensure the Row/Col the VMVH is on are * sized and that its Alignments are stretched then it ought to work.

Comment: Ah, it turns out the binding was silently failing for the third user control. I solved this and everything is rendered as I had hoped. Thanks for all your help, it is very much appreciated.